# Andengine BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas max Size

Tags: android, box2d, game-physics, andengine, andengine-gles-2

I'm making a "ground" for mt game , did an image with photoshop about 10,000 X 800 pixels
this is the whole level (Mountions , and ect)

I put this Image in PhysicEditor and got an XML that will give my the "Physics Body"
But when I'm running the app I keep getting Out Of memory Exception

What is the best why to set ground like those? Thanks

Comment: Try making the ground in smaller pieces and only load the parts that the user can see at the current time.

Comment: and this technique won't make the game "lag" meaning there will be a jumps when I load the ground elements when the game is played?

Comment: Of course it will always take time to load things, but smaller pieces will load quicker. You could perhaps do the loading in a separate thread, but that introduces many other problems. I hope nobody told you game programming would be easy :)